# How to check if the user had input nothing strings?

Tags: c++

How I'm I going to add another condition in case the user didn't put anything in both username and password? ( "Empty Username and/or Password - Username and Password required!. Try Again? (Y/N)" )

here's my. code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;
using namespace std;
string username;
string password;
string choice;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
do {

Username:
std::cout << "Enter Username: ";
std::cin >> username;

if (username != "Joven")
{
std::cout << "Invalid Username. Please try again.\n\n\n";
goto choice;
goto Username;

}
Password:
std::cout << "Enter Password: ";
std::cin >> password;

if (password != "Fabricante7188")
{
std::cout << "Invalid Password. Please try again.\n\n\n";
std::cout << "Do you want to try again? y/n \n\n";
cin >> choice;
goto Password;
}
else
{
std::cout << "Correct Username and Password - Log In Successfull.\n";
break;

choice:
std::cout << "Do you want to try again? y/n \n\n";
std::cin >> choice;

}
}while (choice != "y" && choice != "n");

if (choice != "y" && choice != "n")
{
cout << "Invalid choice.\n";
goto choice;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}`
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: On an unrelated note, using `goto` as loops is not something you should do as a habit. Using `goto` in general is something you should avoid altogether.

Comment: On another unrelated note, you should never write two `goto` statements in a row, like you did with `goto choice; goto Username;`. This kind of code may only be used in satirical code making fun of Apple's SSL code, where it appeared as `goto fail; goto fail;`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the input operation `>>` you can't. It will block until there is some actual non-space input followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (or there's an error or "end of file").

The C++ standard solution (without resorting to OS specific functionality) is to read a whole like using e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), strip the input of leading (and possibly trailing) spaces, and then see if the resulting string is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be something like this: (Edited by scorch 2017/01/14 10:24 AEST)

```
//#include "stdafx.h"       I made this a comment because I don't appear to have this file. It wasn't necessary for me. Don't know whether you need it or not.
// include statements must not end with semicolons.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>  // Has system() function
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Always declare variables inside the function.
    string username;
    string password;
    string choice;
    bool finished = false; // Declare this.
    bool askingToTryAgain = false; // For when the user is asked whether they want to try again.

    do {

        std::cout << "Enter Username: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, username);

        std::cout << "Enter Password: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, password);

        // Validate username and password.
        if (username != "Joven" && password != "Fabricante7188") {
            // If both the username and password are invalid, report it.
            std::cout << "Invalid Username and Password. Try again? (y/n): ";
        } else if (username == "Joven" && password == "Fabricante7188") {
            // If both fields are valid, login is successful.
            std::cout << "Correct Username and Password - Log In Successful.\n";
            finished = true; // Login is now complete, the loop will end.
        } else {
            // If just one of the fields is invalid, report which one it is.
            if (username != "Joven") {
                std::cout << "Invalid Username. Try again? (y/n): ";
            }
            if (password != "Fabricante7188") {
                std::cout << "Invalid Password. Try again? (y/n): ";
            }
        }

        if (finished == false) {
            // If the login was unsuccessful, await user input for whether they wish to try again or not.
            askingToTryAgain = true;

            do {
                // Fetch user input (y/n)
                std::getline(std::cin, choice);
                // Validate it.
                if (choice != "y" && choice != "n") {
                    std::cout << "Enter 'y' or 'n'\n";
                } else {
                    askingToTryAgain = false;

                    if (choice == "y") {
                        // Nothing to do here. The parent loop will continue after this one stops.
                    } else if (choice == "n") {
                        finished = true; // The user wishes to quit.
                    }
                }
            } while (askingToTryAgain);

        }

    } while (finished == false);

    system("pause"); // During testing I used 'sleep 4' (sleep for 4 seconds) because I'm running Linux.
    return 0;
}
```

Also, please do yourself a favour and avoid using 'goto' as a way to control the flow of program execution. Loops and conditions are a far better solution in a structured programming language such as C++ than the 'goto' statements.

I suggest you have a look at http://cplusplus.com/ as a good reference tool.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Want to try your code  but unfortunately it wont run in my VS. It keeps getting errors!

Comment: Ok. I'd need to see your compiler output. What sort of errors have you received? I'll try it in my environment and edit my code to correct any errors.

Comment: I have tested and modified my code so now it works. Removed syntax errors and added a new boolean variable. I have updated my post to include the full solution. Hopefully it works for you now.